# run a macro on another workbook and then close the workbook that launched the macro

Tags: vba, excel, macros

How to
1. Run macro from current (FIRST.XLSM) workbook to open another workbook(SECOND.XLSM)
2. Run Macro on (SECOND.XLSM) workbook that closes (FIRST.XLSM) and then continues its procedure
I tried this:

```
Sub FirstMacro()
Workbooks.Open Range("f90")        'second workbook full path

Workbooks("first.XLSM").Close SaveChanges:=True  'save first workbook and close
Second_Workbook_Macro ' run second workbook macro
End Sub
```

But since it saves and closes the first workbook the vba doesn't continue its procedure ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Sub FirstMacro()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open Range("f90")   'second workbook full path

    Application.Run "'" & wb.Name & "'!Second_Workbook_Macro"

    ThisWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True  'save first workbook and close

End Sub
```

Comment: THANKS TIM FOR YOUR REPLY...
THIS VBA YOU SUGGESTED CLOSE THE FIRST WORKBOOK AFTER THE VBA IN SECOND WORKBOOK COMPLETES ITS OWN MACRO...I NEED TO CLOSE FIRST WORKBOOK BEFORE VBA IN SECOND WORKBOOK DO ITS JOB
AS THE FIRST WORKBOOK SLOW DOWN THE SECOND WORKBOOK CALCULATIONS DURING THE RUN OF ITS VBA

Comment: Instead of using Application.Run, try using `Application.OnTime` to schedule the other macro with a short delay, so you can close the first workbook.

Comment: worked perfectly ... thanks Tim for your Short and effective solution